# Rules: fire at adding term only when one of this term anscestors is other specific term

Tags: 7, rules

I'm trying to add menu items programatically by using rules - the item should be added after user will create a term, but I need a specific condition that I cannot accomplish - fire rule only if ONE OF THE ANCESTORS of created term is specific term. So for example if I have hierarchy:

```
Term 1
Term 2
 - Term 2.1
 - Term 2.2
   -Term 2.2.1
```

I would like the rule to fire when the added term is 2.x.x.x... How can I accomplish this? I was trying for few hours different approaches without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own condition for rules

```
function mymodule_rules_condition_info() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_condition_needs_veryfication' => array(
      'label' => t('ONE OF THE ANCESTORS of created term is specific term'),
      'group' => t('mymodule'),
      'arguments' => array(
        'aplication_node' => array(
            'type' => 'node',
            'label' => t('A fancy condition'),
        ),
      ),
      'module' => 'mymodule',
    ),
  );
}
function mymodule_condition_needs_veryfication($node) 
  if(condition($node))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```